# Как сделать navtabs, если список табов берется из бд. vue.js, vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Я новечок во vue, пишу чат в целях практики. Есть компонент отображающий список групп, на которые подписан пользователь, при нажатии на группу в списке, соотвественно, должен отобразить чат группы (работает это примерно как navtabs), список груп достается из бд при помощи vuex.

```
<template>
    <div class="channel-list">
        <div class="channel-title">
            <span>Channels</span>
            <span class="count">{{allChannels.length}}</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="list">
            <li v-for="(channel, index) in allChannels" 
                :class="classes" 
                :key="index"
            >
                {{channel.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: 'ChannelList',
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {
            classes: {
                ['channel-item']: true,
                active: false
            },
            channels: {
                ...this.allChannels
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            allChannels: 'channels/allChannels'
        })
    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>
```

Не могу придумать как в компоненте отслеживать какой элемент списка групп был нажат, как навесить на него состояние активности и убрать это состояние с предыдущего нажатого элемента списка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно правильно реализовать.

Comment: У вас вопрос в заголовке не совпадает с вопросом в последнем абзаце.

Comment: Если необходимо кликом подсветить элемент, то это можно сделать, используя переменную target. При клике, элемент записывает себя в переменную target и как-то себя подсвечивает. При клике по другому элементу происходит отмена подсветки старого таргета, подсветка нового и перезапись переменной